# Find and replace: "Replace with" contains dollar sign ($)

Tags: excel-formula

In an Excel (O365) spreadsheet, the name `MI` refers to cell `C8`. `MI` is used in a lot of formulas in that sheet. I want to find and replace each occurence of `MI` within the formulas by the direct reference `$C$8`. When I do the following ...

- Strg + H (find and replace)
- Find what: `MI`
- Replace with: `$C$8`
- Look in: `Formulas`

... I get the error message:

*There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel
thinks it's a formula [...]*

The problem seems to be the dollar sign in the replace string. If I replace with `C8` instead of `$C$8` everything works well. How can I replace with `$C$8` ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: are you sure you do not have any formula that use `MI` as the formula like `MID`, `MIN`, `MINIFS`,...?

Comment: I would suggest, instead of `Replace All` you step through each with `Find Next` and `Replace` only those that make sense.

Comment: Scott, thanks for your comment. That's no issue in my specific case since I have no other function names in the formulas of the respective cells. The problem is that Replace does not work at all because anything is "wrong" with the "$".

Comment: Have you stepped through to verify.  The only reason you would get that error is that you are trying to replace a formula or other named range the includes the `MI` in them.  for example `$C$8NUTE(A1)` would return the error you are showing, but `C8NUTE(A1)` would return a `#NAME` error in the cell.  Some where you are replacing the wrong thing.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Now I got it! There is another name in the formula which also contains "MI". I was blind (and my first reply was stupid) ... Thank you so much!